# "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" error - Vue 3 and Quasar component tested with Jest.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have to test a component in the application Vue 3 and Quasar with Webpack. This is an example of my test:

```
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { installQuasarPlugin } from '@quasar/quasar-app-extention-testing-unit-jest'

installQuasarPlugin();

describe('Deployment of MyComponent', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent)
    const toolbar = wrapper.findComponent({name: 'QToolbar'}) 

    it('MyComponent renders correctly', () => {
        
        expect(toolbar.exist()).toBe(true)

    })

});
```

When I run the test I have the error: "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"
and error is shown in const wrapper when I mount the component.
I've written other tests in the same way, which works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed a little my script like this:

```
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('Deployment of MyComponent', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent)

    it('MyComponent renders correctly', () => {
        
        expect(wrapper.exist()).toBe(true)

    })

});
```

I've removed installQuasarPlugin() and tests work but in the console, I have a warning like this: "Filed to resolve component: q-toolbar, If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomelement."

So I resolve it only partially